# SDL Tridion smartTarget & Adobe Equivalent

Tags: 2013, smarttarget

I'm brand new to SDL Tridion and am evaluating SDL Tridion CMS versus Adobe CQ.

I've read that implementing SDL Tridion with SDL SmartTarget is quite complex.

My question: what is the Adobe equivalent of something like SDL SmartTarget?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Adobe CQ

Comment: I don't think you can really compare ST with Adobe's T&T. ST is designed & built for website managers to control promotions, while T&T is designed for "Data Marketeers". ST keeps control of the site in the CM side of the house, while T&T gives it away to the "Product Marketing" side of the house... so different objectives, different teams, different concepts. Whether it's easier or harder... you'd have to ask someone who did both.

Comment: Implementing SDL Tridion with SDL SmartTarget is no more complex than implementing any other software suite. The complexity of any project is gathering and refining the business requirements.

Comment: I answered my own question and apologize for the off-topic question. I should have read the help center first. Thanks.